# Can not deserialize json to Dictionary<string, List<Purchase>>

Tags: c#, json

I can not deserialize json to `Dictionary<string, List<Purchas>>` in C#.

Here is my `.json`:

```
{
  "Ukraine": {
    {
      "Credits": 500,
      "Name": "Clever goat",
      "Price": {
        "Amount": 100,
        "Currency": "UAH"
      }
    },
    {
      "Credits": 1000,
      "Name": "Smart hare",
      "Price": {
        "Amount": 190,
        "Currency": "UAH"
      }
    }
  },

  "USA": {
    {
      "Credits": 500,
      "Name": "Clever goat",
      "Price": {
        "Amount": 10,
        "Currency": "USD"
      }
    },
    {
      "Credits": 1000,
      "Name": "Smart hare",
      "Price": {
        "Amount": 19,
        "Currency": "USD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my `Purchase` class:

```
public class Price
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Purchase
{
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I am trying to deserialize it:

```
var countryToPurchases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Purchase>>>(dataJSON);
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> JsonReaderException: Invalid property identifier character: {. Path 'Ukraine', line 3, position 4.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty()

What am I missing here?

Comment: What did https://jsonlint.com/ say about your JSON?

Comment: @mjwills, hm... Thank you.

Comment: The `Price` property of class `Purchase` should be of type `Price`, not `int`.

Comment: Where did you get that "JSON" from?

Comment: The property with the country name in your JSON should hold an *array* of objects (`[ {...}, {...} ]`). Currently, it merely uses `{` and `}` which is wrong

Comment: to add to the above, the second country object in the array doesn't hold a name, and also Poor naming to the classes, Consider renaming your `Price` class to `PriceData` so that you'll have `public PriceData Price`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. The Json is invalid. There should be arrays there but there aren't.
   A valid json would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "Ukraine": [
      {
        "Credits": 500,
        "Name": "Clever goat",
        "Price": {
          "Amount": 100,
          "Currency": "UAH"
        }
      },
      {
        "Credits": 1000,
        "Name": "Smart hare",
        "Price": {
          "Amount": 190,
          "Currency": "UAH"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "USA": [
      {
        "Credits": 500,
        "Name": "Clever goat",
        "Price": {
          "Amount": 10,
          "Currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      {
        "Credits": 1000,
        "Name": "Smart hare",
        "Price": {
          "Amount": 19,
          "Currency": "USD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

2. The `Price` property should be of type `Price`, not `int`.

```
public class Purchase
{
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please check this json and see if it's works  :

```
 {
 "Ukraine": {
  "Credits": 500,
  "Name": "Clever goat",
  "Price": {
   "Amount": 100,
   "Currency": "UAH"
 }
},
 "USA": {
  "Credits": 500,
  "Name": "Clever goat",
  "Price": {
    "Amount": 10,
    "Currency": "USD"
  }
 }
}
```